# Rails 3.2.11: RailsAdmin localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I've installed rails_admin gem on my localized site (2 languages) and i need administration  (/admin) to be always in English. According to [documentation](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration) I should add following 2 lines to beginning of rails_admin.rb file.

```
require 'i18n'
I18n.default_locale = :de
```

But it's not working. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you changed `:de` to `:en` and tried that?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you have any configuration in you applicacion controller? RailsAdmin inherits from your ApplicationController...

Comment: Thank you for reply. Here is the my source code: https://github.com/galtgaridsoft/moru

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled over the same Issue. Here is how I solved it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Controller
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    if [Clearance, RailsAdmin].include?(self.class.parent)
      I18n.locale = :en
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
end
```

`RailsAdmin` controllers are inheriting form your `ApplicationController` so you need to tell them explicitly to use the locale :en there or you can open the classes and overwrite `set_locale`.

Comment: I came across that, Even though `RailsAdmin` controllers are inheriting from `ApplicationController`, It never triggers 'ApplicationController' when it routes to the '/admin' or '/admin/etc..' so your solution does nothing to do with `RailsAdmin`

Answer (score 1):

It does state on the documentation that you only need to do this if your local is set to something other then English so you may find that you do not need to set this. If you do need to set this then make sure it is below the `RailsAdmin.config do |config|` line in  `rails_admin.rb`

**Update -**

As you are still running into problems could you please let me know what version of ruby you are using? Have you run a `bundle install`? Could you try `sudo gem install i18n`. Also if it cannot find your locales you may need to point it at them i.e `I18n.load_translations "#{RAILS_ROOT}/locales/#{locale}.rb"`

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please see my source code: https://github.com/galtgaridsoft/moru